# bash script does not continue after grep -w -c

Tags: bash

this drives me crazy now:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXISTING_VOLUMES=$(docker volume ls -q | grep -w -c ${VOLUME})
echo "volumes found ${EXISTING_VOLUMES}"
```

if I have a match and the expression returns 1 then the echo is called. However if I dont have a match, then the expression returns `0` but then the echo is never called. why??

Comment: What is value of `$VOLUME` and how do you call your script?

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the script from your post into a new file, run it, and see if you can still reproduce the problem? My guess is that what you posted is in reality part of a larger script that does `set -e` in some form.

Comment: yeah, without the `set -e` it does work